# Agregar string no R

Tags: r

Possuo a seguinte base:

```
cidade      a                 b         c
AGRONOMICA  CRESO             NA        NA
AGRONOMICA  NA                SICOOB    NA
ALFREDO     CREDIVERTENTES    NA        NA
ALMIRANTE   SICOPER           NA        NA
ALMIRANTE   NA                SICRED    NA
ALTO        SICOPER           NA        NA
ALTO        NA                SICOOB    NA
ALTO        NA                NA        SICRED
```

A ideia é agregar a base para que ela fique assim:

```
cidade      a                 b         c
AGRONOMICA  CRESO             SICOOB    NA
ALFREDO     CREDIVERTENTES    NA        NA
ALMIRANTE   SICOPER           SICRED    NA    
ALTO        SICOPER           SICOOB    SICRED
```

O aggregate exige que os valores sejam numéricos.
Como fazer isso com essas variáveis nominais?

Comment: Por que o `ALMIRANTE` não aparece no resultado desejado?

Comment: Era pra ter aparecido. Foi erro na hora de colocar a resposta

Comment: Porque é que no resultado a linha `ALFREDO` tem a coluna `b` igual a `SICRED` se na tabela de input é `NA`?

Comment: Outro erro. Foi consertado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creio que este código responde à pergunta, mas é preciso ter atenção ao seguinte: no resultado pretendido, que está na pergunta, a linha `ALFREDO` tem a coluna `b` igual a `SICRED` quando na tabela de entrada é `NA`. Então, este código mantém o valor `NA` no resultado.

```
res <- lapply(split(dados, dados$cidade), zoo::na.locf)
res <- lapply(res, zoo::na.locf, fromLast = TRUE)
res <- do.call(rbind, res)
res <- res[!duplicated(res), ]
row.names(res) <- NULL
res
#      cidade              a      b      c
#1 AGRONOMICA          CRESO SICOOB   <NA>
#2    ALFREDO CREDIVERTENTES   <NA>   <NA>
#3  ALMIRANTE        SICOPER SICRED   <NA>
#4       ALTO        SICOPER SICOOB SICRED
```

**Explicação.**
Passo a passo, o código acima funciona do seguinte modo.

1. Em primeiro lugar usa o `split` para dividir a data.frame de entrada por `cidade`.
2. A seguir, aplica a função `na.locf` do pacote `zoo` a cada sub-df para levar o anterior valor que não seja `NA` *para a frente*.
3. Agora faz o mesmo, mas levando o valor não `NA` posterior *para trás*.
4. Depois junta as sub-df's com `do.call/rbind`.
5. E escolhe só as linhas não duplicadas.
6. O resultado tem nomes de linha, para os numerar consecutivamente basta atribuir-lhes o valor `NULL`.

**DADOS.**

```
dados <-
structure(list(cidade = c("AGRONOMICA", "AGRONOMICA", "ALFREDO", 
"ALMIRANTE", "ALMIRANTE", "ALTO", "ALTO", "ALTO"), a = c("CRESO", 
NA, "CREDIVERTENTES", "SICOPER", NA, "SICOPER", NA, NA), b = c(NA, 
"SICOOB", NA, NA, "SICRED", NA, "SICOOB", NA), c = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "SICRED")), .Names = c("cidade", "a", "b", 
"c"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Answer (score 0):

O pacote purrrlyr torna  a excelente solução do @Rui mais simples:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrrlyr)
library(zoo)

dados %>% 
  group_by(cidade) %>% 
  dmap(na.locf) %>% 
  distinct(cidade,.keep_all=T)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sem precisar de nada além do dplyr:

```
dados %>%
  group_by(cidade) %>%
  summarise_all(function(x) {
    res <- x[!is.na(x)]
    ifelse(length(res) == 0, NA_character_, res)
  })
```